# How to retrieve text colum from sql java?

Tags: java, sql, string, netbeans

I have a table. The table has a column `'Column1'` which is of type `'text'`.

How can I retrieve the text and store it as a string?

The below is what I attempted. (But it does not work, I get weird characters back, instead of the data within the database)

```
   public void getConfigurationXML()
   {
       try
       {            
           Class.forName("java.sql.Driver"); 
           Connection conn=(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection(_url,_user,_pwd); 
           Statement st=conn.createStatement(); 

           ArrayList <String[]> result = new ArrayList<String[]>();
           String query ="SELECT Column1 FROM table1";
           ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(query); 
           int columnCount = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();

           while(rs.next())
           { 
               String[] row = new String[columnCount];
               for (int i=0; i <columnCount ; i++)
               {
                   row[i] = rs.getString(i + 1);
               }
               result.add(row);
           } 

           rs.close(); 
           st.close(); 
           conn.close(); 

      } 
      catch(Exception e)
      { 
           Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName());
           lgr.log(Level.WARNING, e.getMessage(), e);
      }
   }
```

Comment: Not related to your problem, but the `close` statements should be put in the `finally` block to make sure closing happens in a structured and safe way.

Comment: Which database is this? The driver looks generic.

Comment: Seems like you are using different character encoding in your database. That is the reason you are getting "weird characters"

Comment: How to deal with a `text` column depends completely on your DBMS (`text` in PostgreSQL is something completely different than `text` in SQL Server). So please let us know which DBMS you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about the `text` datatype that is used for BLOB structures, you can try this:

```
java.sql.Blob ablob = rs.getBlob(i + 1);
row[i] = new String(ablob.getBytes(1L, (int) ablob.length()));
```

The reason for the weird characters is that the database stores this as raw bytes instead of the characters that you're expecting.

Comment: If the DBMS is PostgreSQL then `text` is definitely not a `BLOB`